# Postgresql database connection code in c# dotnet linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm new to Linux, dotnet and postgres. And I'm trying to write a code for database connection in C#. but I'm getting Error

> "CS0246 The type or namespace name 'NpgsqlConnection' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)."

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64Bit, dnxcore version 5.0, postgresql, npgsql 3.1.0-alpha6. i've defined dependency in project.jason as "Npgsql": "3.1.0-alpha6".
My code is,

```
using System;
using npgsql;
namespace testdbconn
{
  public class tstdb
    {
         NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;UserId=postgres;Password=mypass;Database=xxxxx;");

         public static void Main()
              {
                    OpenConn();
              }
         public static void OpenConn()
              {
                   try
                   {               
                         conn.Open();
                   }
                  catch (Exception exp)
                   {                
                         MessageBox.Show("Error :S");
                   }
              }
    }
}
```

can someone help me out, I'm completely lost. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added *relevant* assembly I think that's because you write your namespace without care it's case. It should be like;

```
using Npgsql;
```

Namespace names are case sensitive.

Also don't use `NpgsqlConnection` object as a field in your application. Define them in your method.

Comment: Thanks, now I've new errors, but error cs0246 is gone.